# Menu positioned incorrectly after hovering a MenuItem element (Material-UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When hovering a MenuItem, the positon of the Menu container should not change.

- [x] The issue is present in the latest release. Please not that if you downgrade MUI to v4.5.0 
  It behaves as expected.

### Current Behavior

When hovering a MenuItem, the positon of the Menu container changes.

### Expected Behavior

When hovering a MenuItem, the positon of the Menu container should not change.

### Steps to Reproduce

Steps:

1. Open https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-ritchie-9pxh2 (MUI 4.9.5)
2. Hover the second ListItem, notice a text appears.
3. Click the first MenuItem after the Menu appears.
   Notice: If you downgrade MaterialUI to 4.5.0 It behaves as expected.
   Here it works : https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-mountain-rzvbd (MUI version 4.5.0)

Comment: Hm..Using Firefox Nightly 76, both behave with the error and the console throw some messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most-likely due to this PR: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/19046.

Use visibility to hide the element which is the anchor (to make it stay in the DOM) - this will ensure your menu will not move to a wrong position.

```
        <ListItemIcon
          style={{ visibility: hoveredItem ? "visible" : "hidden" }}
          onClick={e => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            onClickSideText(e);
          }}
        >
```

Or you can hide/show the element based on whether Menu is visible or not. In this case you have to hive the hoveredItem when you close the menu.

```
  const onMenuItemLeave = e => {
    if (!anchorElelement.anchorEl) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      setHoveredItem(null);
    }
  };

  const closeItemMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElelement({});
    setHoveredItem(null);
  };
```